# Permanent Polymorph Any Object and levelling up

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, polymorph

Suppose a character is under the effect of a [Polymorph Any Object](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/polymorphAnyObject.htm) spell with a duration of Permanent. When they gain their next level, they gain an ability score increase and apply it to one of the stats that is permanently changed (Str, Dex, Con, or Int). Then, later, the effect is dispelled. What happens to the stat boost? Is that lost, as well? Does it carry back to the original character's stats? This carry-over seems to be one way if it does, as you do not augment your polymorphed form with previously attained ability score increases. But it also seems pretty harsh to have the character lose the ability score increase after they succeed on removing the Polymorph Any Object spell.

Similarly, what happens if a wizard turns themself into an ethergaunt permanently. This provides a rather small, but not insubstantial, intelligence boost. If they gain levels while they are an ethergaunt, would they gain more skill points than normal for having a higher intelligence score?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Polymorph grants you the statistics of the creature you polymorph into however when it expires they revert.  Permanancy doesn't do anything except extend that change permanently. It doesn't mean the creature's stats are now your own.

For example, if you have a character whose strength is 10 and you polymorph into something whose strength is 18, when you level, you could adjust your strength score to 11 but it has no effect on the polymorphed creature's strength, which would remain 18.  In other words, you do not get 19 strength when leveling because you leveled when you were polymorphed.  The stats increasing would be your own, and the only ones used would be the ones not affected by the spell (in the case of Polymorph any Object: Wisdom and Charisma), otherwise you use the creature's stats for the duration of the spell (in your example, permanently until dispelled).

Comment: It should be noted that permanency can be dispelled.

Comment: @PlayPatrice Was "(in your example, permanently until dispelled)" not clear enough?  Happy to improve my answer but not sure exactly what wasn't clear.

Answer (score -1):

In the [answer from joedragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/180615/44723) I would question if you're leveling up multiple times and you put anything in a physical stat that it wouldn't affect the body you have at the time so I would probably just stick to increasing con, int, cha, and wis or at least transfer the points 1 for 1 when changed back but that's just me personally.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/81894)